# Android In App Purchases

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

I have created an android app which has two activities one is ad free and another has ads. I want to create in app purchases for removing ads so when the user purchases the app it shows him adfree activity and if not it shows him activity with ads. Can someone tell me how to do it. Here is my code.

```
import cf.droiddev.androidtutorials.util.IabHelper;
import cf.droiddev.androidtutorials.util.IabResult;
import cf.droiddev.androidtutorials.util.Inventory;
import cf.droiddev.androidtutorials.util.Purchase;

public class RemoveAdsActivity extends Activity {

static final String TAG = "Android Tutorials";

static final String SKU_INAPPITEM = "android.test.purchased"; //"change to your in app item"; // "android.test.cancelled";

String base64EncodedPublicKey = "REPLACE WITH YOUR PUBLIC KEY";

// The helper object
IabHelper mHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.remove_ads_activity);

    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set
    // this to false).
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);

    // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener
    // will be called once setup completes.
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                return;
            }

            // Hooray, IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of
            // stuff we own.
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });

}

// Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and
// subscriptions we own
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
            Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

        /*
         * Check for items we own. Notice that for each purchase, we check
         * the developer payload to see if it's correct! See
         * verifyDeveloperPayload().
         */

        // Check for gas delivery -- if we own gas, we should fill up the
        // tank immediately
        Purchase removeAdsPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_INAPPITEM);
        if (removeAdsPurchase != null
                && verifyDeveloperPayload(removeAdsPurchase)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "User has already purchased this item for removing ads. Write the Logic for removign Ads.");
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_INAPPITEM),
                    mConsumeFinishedListener);
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
    }

};

// User clicked the "Buy Gas" button
public void onBuyGasButtonClicked(View arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Buy gas button clicked.");

    /*
     * TODO: for security, generate your payload here for verification. See
     * the comments on verifyDeveloperPayload() for more info. Since this is
     * a SAMPLE, we just use an empty string, but on a production app you
     * should carefully generate this.
     */
    String payload = "";

    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_INAPPITEM, 10000,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + ","
            + data);

    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }
}

// Callback for when a purchase is finished
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: "
                + purchase);
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Error purchasing: " + result);
            return;
        }
        if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
            complain("Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed.");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_INAPPITEM)) {
            // bought 1/4 tank of gas. So consume it.
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "removeAdsPurchase was succesful.. starting consumption.");
            mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
        }
    }
};

// Called when consumption is complete
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Consumption finished. Purchase: " + purchase
                + ", result: " + result);

        // We know this is the "gas" sku because it's the only one we
        // consume,
        // so we don't check which sku was consumed. If you have more than
        // one
        // sku, you probably should check...
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // successfully consumed, so we apply the effects of the item in
            // our
            // game world's logic, which in our case means filling the gas
            // tank a bit
            Log.d(TAG, "Consumption successful. Provisioning.");
            alert("You have purchased for removing ads from your app.");
        } else {
            complain("Error while consuming: " + result);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "End consumption flow.");
    }
};

/** Verifies the developer payload of a purchase. */
boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
    String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();

    /*
     * TODO: verify that the developer payload of the purchase is correct.
     * It will be the same one that you sent when initiating the purchase.
     * 
     * WARNING: Locally generating a random string when starting a purchase
     * and verifying it here might seem like a good approach, but this will
     * fail in the case where the user purchases an item on one device and
     * then uses your app on a different device, because on the other device
     * you will not have access to the random string you originally
     * generated.
     * 
     * So a good developer payload has these characteristics:
     * 
     * 1. If two different users purchase an item, the payload is different
     * between them, so that one user's purchase can't be replayed to
     * another user.
     * 
     * 2. The payload must be such that you can verify it even when the app
     * wasn't the one who initiated the purchase flow (so that items
     * purchased by the user on one device work on other devices owned by
     * the user).
     * 
     * Using your own server to store and verify developer payloads across
     * app installations is recommended.
     */

    return true;
}

void complain(String message) {
    Log.e(TAG, "**** IN APP Purchase Error: " + message);
    alert(message);
}

void alert(String message) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Showing alert dialog: " + message);
    TextView resultTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_result);
    resultTv.setText("Result : " + message);
}

}
```

Also can anyone tell me how to create developer payload any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to answer the main question here ^^
If not done already set the Activity with ads as launching Activity. In the onCreate() method in that Activity, you'll add the follwing thing at the end of onCreate():

```
if([Purchased?]
{
Intent adfreeactivity = new Intent(NameOfCurrentActivity.this, NameOfTargetActivity.class);
startActivity(adfreeactivity);
}
```

After that, your app should start the right activity on start.
Additionally, if the user once goes offline, better save the result in the SharedPreferences, and only check again when the user is online, and let the Activity only switch when the last check returned a successful purchase.

Hope I could help you,
Max Müller